# Apache Hive on Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

Does anyone has worked on this configuration: Apache Hive on Apache Spark?

What is the latest version compatibility for this configuration?

I want to implement this in my production systems. Kindly help with the compatibility matrix for Apache Hadoop, Apache Hive, Apache Spark and Apache Zeppelin.

Comment: Try reading the documentation? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started Also, Zeppelin doesn't care (as long as you have a configured JDBC interpreter: The Spark interpreter isn't using HiveServer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `hive2` (0.11+)  and `SPARK 2.2.0` and in `hive-site.xml`. And you have to set Spark as executor engine so you can easily run your queries on top of Spark.

In `hive2` there are some options like `Tez`, `llap` etc. For more information kindly check the document [Hive on Spark: Getting Started](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started).

Comment: link is missing from your answer

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar here it is https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started

Comment: i have already edited sahil's answer. Please go through it again and u ll find that link

Comment: am getting below error while running in beeline select count(*) from student;
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Failed to execute spark task, with exception 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask (state=08S01,code=1)

Answer (score 0):

follow the tutorial

[apache hive installation](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Hive_Install_On_Ubuntu_16_04.php)

and then just copy the hive-site.xml to $APACHE_HOME/conf

Answer (score 0):

Hive is moving to rely only on the Tez execution engine.  Please build all new workloads on MapReduce or Tez.